# Dynamically adding two form elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create two form elements when the user clicks a button, which he can do 5 times, but I am new to jQuery so I am running into problems,

here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
        var num     = $('.clonedInput').length; 
        var numTwo     = $('.clonedInputTwo').length; 
        var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);      

        var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);
        var newElemTwo = $('#inputTwo' + numTwo).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);


        newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);
        newElemTwo.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);


        $('#input' + num).after(newElem);
        $('#inputTwo' + numTwo).after(newElemTwo);

        $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','');

        if (newNum == 5)
            $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
    });

        $('#btnDel').click(function() {
            var num = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
            $('#input' + num).remove();     // remove the last element
            $('#inputTwo' + num).remove();     // remove the last element

            // enable the "add" button
            $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','');

            // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
            if (num-1 == 1)
                $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
        });

        $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
    });
```

The HTML:

```
<form id='myForm'>
    <div id='input1' style='margin-bottom:4px;' class='clonedInput'>
        Name: <input type='text' name='name1' id='name1' />
    </div>
    <div id='inputTwo1' style='margin-bottom:4px;' class='clonedInputTwo'>
        School: <input type='text' name='nameTwo1' id='nameTwo1' />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type='button' id='btnAdd' value='add another name' />
        <input type='button' id='btnDel' value='remove name' />
    </div>
</form>
```

When I click the button it works once, then it just proceeds to create name elements, and no school elements!

Comment: Created jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/e6cwd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var newElemTwo = $('#inputTwo' + numTwo).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);
```

should be

```
var newElemTwo = $('#inputTwo' + numTwo).clone().attr('id', 'inputTwo' + newNum);
```

Take a [look](http://jsfiddle.net/e6cwd/1/) (thanks to MvanGeest)

Comment: Thanx, that worked great! One more thing, is there a way to create the elements in such a way that it could be arranged as Name:School:Name:School:Name:School etc etc?

Comment: Why not put `Name` and `School` in a `div` and then clone the `div`? Should be easier if the fields only appear in pairs... and it would make cleaner code.

Comment: +1 for being first and this fixes yours on top (easier navigation)

Comment: Or how can I add line breaks after each element?

Comment: Excuse me, about doing what? There are line breaks after each element.

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/e6cwd/9/ It's still not very beautiful, but it's better. Would you like an even more flexible version, which allows for more fields?

Comment: Thank you so much! If you wouldn't mind, that would be great!